# Dropping columns before a matching string in the following column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

Is there direct possibility to drop all columns before a matching string in a pandas Dataframe. For eg. if my column 8 contains a string 'Matched' I want to drop columns 0 to 7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you did not give any information where and how to look  for 'Matched', but let's say that integer `col_num` contains the number of the matched column:

```
col_num = np.where(df == 'Matched')[1][0]
df.drop(columns=df.columns[0:col_num],inplace=True)
```

will do the drop

Comment: Yea. Finding the col_num is my actual problem. Say my df has 15 columns all of which are Unnamed. Of these 15 only one column (any row) will have the value 'Matched'

Comment: And what if there are few columns with 'matched'? use the first?

Comment: Yea. But only one column will have the string.

Comment: See above. Added the calculation of col_num

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
data = {'A': {0: 1}, 'B': {0: 2}, 'C': {0: 3}, 'Match1': {0: 4}, 'D': {0: 5}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df`

```
    A   B   C   Match1  D
0   1   2   3   4       5
```

---

**Code**

remove in front of first Match + @ column : `boolean indexing`

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith('Match').cumsum() > 0]
```

`result`

```
    Match1  D
0   4       5
```

Comment: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'cmsum' I get this error

Comment: It seems to be a version problem. Try running it on Google colab.